# Component in Scrollview for stickyHeaderIndices

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use Scrollview with stickyHeaderIndices.
My problem is the content of Scrollview is return by an other component so is wrap in Fragment view.
And the stickyHeaderIndices does not work.

You have an idea to resolve the problem ?
I can't generate the Scrollview on child component. I have a refreshControl associate to the parent component.

Example :

```
<ScrollView
   refreshControl={<RefreshComponent ... />}
 >
   {props.children}
</ScrollView>
```

And children look like :

```
<>
 <View>....</View>
 <View>....</View>
 <View>....</View>
 ...
</>
```

I can't remove the fragment `<></>` because it's mandatory for a component to return one child component.

Thanks !